# How to fix: 'TypeError: fetchProducts is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to retrieve a set of products from an API using a redux store.

To achieve this, I created actions and reducers, a function `mapStateToProps()` and a function `mapDispatchToProps()`, the latter one contains a function `fetchProducts()`, which is defined in the action file and should retrieve the list of products when called.

All of this is done in the following way:

This is the overview component, which should render the data (the actual rendering is left out, because it does not affect this question):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import fetchProductsAction from '../actions/ProductFetchingActionFile'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

export class Overview extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProducts();
    }

    render() {
        return(
                  <h1>test</h1>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    error: state.rootReducer.productsReducer.error,
    products: state.rootReducer.productsReducer.products,
    pending: state.rootReducer.productsReducer.pending,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    fetchProducts: fetchProductsAction 
}, dispatch)

Overview.propTypes = {
    fetchProducts: PropTypes.func
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Overview);
```

This is the action file (ProductFetchingActionFile):

```
import {
    PREFIX,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR
} from "./types";

function fetchProductsPending() {
    return{
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING
    }
}

function fetchProductsSuccess(products) {
    return{
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        products: products
    }
}

function fetchProductsError(error) {
    return{
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
        error: error
    }
}

function fetchProducts() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsPending());
        return fetch(`localhost:8080/products`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if(res.error) {
                    throw(res.error);
                }
                dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(res));
                return res
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchProductsError(error));
            })
    }
}

export default fetchProducts
```

This is the reducer file:

```
import {
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR
} from "./types"


const initialState = {
    pending: false,
    products: [],
    error: null
}

export function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING:
        return {
            ...state,
            pending: true
        }
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            pending: false,
            products: action.products
        }
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
        return {
            ...state,
            pending: false,
            error: action.error
        }
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Now, I get the following error when the Overview component is loaded:
`TypeError: fetchProducts is not a function`. This error fires on the call to `fetchProducts` in the `componentDidMount()` function.

Also, when the Overview.props is printed in the console before this call, it does not contain the function `fetchProducts`, so I suspect that it has to do something with the `mapDispatchToProps`, but I cannot find the problem.

Edit: it is good to note that if the imported `fetchProductsAction` is printed in the constructor of the `Overview` component, it shows the correct function. It does however not end up in the `props` of `Overview`, so I expect the problem to be there.

Comment: According to this source: https://dev.to/markusclaus/fetching-data-from-an-api-using-reactredux-55ao, it is possible to rename something you import in the import statement.

Comment: With all respect to the source... Isn't it easier to follow official source like this one https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react The way your source is using redux is just terrible. Sorrry

Comment: Try `export default function fetchProducts()` and remove the last export default.

Comment: This seems impossible, this gives the error: `unexpected token, expected "{"` on `export default function fetchProducts()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
       fetchProducts : () => {
            dispatch(fethcProducts())
         }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still generates the exact same error

Comment: Answers which explain changes to code are less often downvoted than those which just say "try this" and some code. You've also misspelled fetchProducts in the code.

Comment: you can import fetchProductsAction from '.types' Js file not from  ProductFetchingActionFile

Answer (score 0):

You're importing your action as

```
import fetchProductsAction from '../actions/ProductFetchingActionFile'
```

when it looks like it's not being exported as a default.

It should probably be:

```
import { fetchProductsAction } from '../actions/ProductFetchingActionFile'
```

Comment: If I do this, I have to remove the `export default fetchProducts` statement from the action file and change `function fetchCourses()` function into `export function fetchCourses()`. However, this still results in the same error. It is good to note however, that if `fetchProductsAction` is printed in the console, it shows the right function. However, it does not end up in props, so I expect the problem to be there.